# Handling page Sessions in helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 web page that I want to show page generation times in milliseconds. To help with code re-use, I have created a PageHelper static class, which I want a 'StartTimer' method, and an 'EndTimer' method. StartTimer returns void, and EndTimer returns a `TimeSpan`.

Because a few pages can used in a single 'page hit', I am putting the StartTime into a `Session[]` variable.

```
public static class PageHelpers
{
    public static void StartPageTimer()
    {
        var StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Session["StartTime"] = StartTime;

    }

    public TimeSpan StopTimer()
    {
        var EndTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration = (EndTime - DateTime.Parse(Session["StartTime"].ToString()));
        return duration;
    }
}
```

The problem I face, is that the Session doesn't seem to be available in this class.... Is there some form of Context or something, which I need to pass to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Please refer this article.

[How to access an ASP.NET Session object inside a static function](http://www.apijunkie.com/APIJunkie/blog/post.aspx?id=20113ce7-1fdf-4058-8433-66f042527faa)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[]`.